# Why is Storybook not showing a React component on the sidebar?

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I've been researching this, but I couldn't find any solutions.
Inside the `.storybook'` folder, there's a `main.js` file, and in it, there is this line:
`stories: ["../src/**/*.stories.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)", "../tmp/**/*.story.mdx"],` which several people have said is the solution to a React component not showing, but I have it, and it's still not showing!

I also tried deleting the `.cache` folder in `.node_modules`, but still not working!

I build and re-started storybook several times already.

I know the component itself works, because, there are two react components that I need, and both are done in two different github branches, and checking out into each branch allows you to run storybook and see that the component I want is showing and working properly. But I need both components on the same place, and I tried to re-create one of them into the branch of the other, but it's not showing on storybook! The component code is identical, so I know it's not a problem with the code or the component. It has to be something related to storybook.

Do you have any other ideas? Anything I'm missing to check, or adjust? I don't really know much about storybook, so keep that in mind. It's just used here in this company, and that's the only way to run your React components.

I don't get any errors on my vscode either!

Comment: Did you check the browser console for errors? I have noticed that sometimes errors are hidden in the browser dev console